# Angular 5 - onclick event append component into div

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I am using Angular 5 and I have this:

```
// app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  appendToContainer() {
    // Do the stuff here
    // Append PanelComponent into div#container
  }

}
```

Now the app.component.html

```
// app.component.html
<button (click)="appendToContainer()"></button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

and finally I have a simple component

```
// panel.component.html
<div class="panelComponent">
  This is a panel Component html
</div>
```

What I want to do is that everytime the button on app.component.html is click I need a panel.component appended into app.component.html

How can I do this?

Comment: I have the feeling you take that problem from the wrong side. Shouldn't you iterate an array with a `*ngFor`?

Comment: you can use an object array that you can append to when calling `appendToContainer` and use `*ngFor` to create a panel for each item in the array

Comment: What I want to do it the create a new instance on the component and append it inside the div when the button is clicked

Comment: @pedromartinez did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *ngFor and a variable to achieve you want

```
//In your component
num:number=0

//You html like 
<button (click)="num++"></button>
//we create a array "on fly" and slice to get only a "num" items
<div *ngFor="let item in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].slice(0,num)" class="panelComponent">
  This is a panel Component html
</div>
```

Comment: What I want to do it the create a new instance on the component and append it inside the div when the button is clicked

Comment: Perhapf some like https://blog.dmbcllc.com/dynamically-add-components-in-angular/ ?

Comment: Seems that the code there is not for angular 5. Here's my app.component.ts: import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from './child/child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {}
  addCmp() {
    console.log('adding');
    // Add an instance of ChildComponent
  }
}