# (click) event not working while append any data in ANGULAR 4

Tags: jquery, angular, angular4-forms

while i am trying to append the "**tr tag**" (click) event was not working in angular 4, here is my Code.

```
$('#time_table_table tbody').append('<tr data-id="1"><td>Sunday<a (click)="assign(1)">Assign</a></td></tr>');
```

when i am trying to "**console.log(id)**" in "**assign()**" function it will not call.

Comment: You cannot mix jQuery and Angular for manipulating the same part of the DOM. Angular does not need just a DOM element, it needs to wire up everything. Just appending a element to the DOM wont tell Angular what is happening

Comment: @NoémiSalaün then how can i append the <tr> tag without using jquery? do you have any other way?

Comment: There are multiple way to do it, it depends on what you are trying to achieve. Maybe you can look into this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/47512731/2459831

Comment: @NoémiSalaün i want to append <tr> tag from component to html.

Comment: If you  don't know what component you will append, you can look for dynamic component, but it is way more complicated https://blog.dmbcllc.com/dynamically-add-components-in-angular/

Comment: You shouldn't think about appending element into the DOM. Maybe you should create a component which iterate over an array with *ngFor, and when you want to append something to the DOM, you can simply push the data into the array, and Angular will create the corresponding DOM and append it to you component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if i am use click Event then can i get it's value in Component in
>   "assign(id)" function?

You should be able to do that. Grab your table with @ViewChild (as I wrote bellow), but before, set template variable - `<table #myTable...` , `@ViewChild('myTable') myTable:ElementRef;`, then create needed elements through Renderer - `let tr1 = this.rd.createElement("tr");` , `let td1 = this.rd.createElement("td");` , `let link1 = this.rd.createElement("a");` , create text nodes with `createText` method, append them to corresponding HTML nodes with `appendChild` and add click handler with `listen()` method - `this.rd.listen(link1, 'click', function(event.target))`. `event.target` will return the reference to the `link1` node. So you could travel up in the HTML tree with `parentElement` property or similar and get the id. You should also be able to pass the parent directly from click handler, like `function(event.target.parentElement)`

---

If you want to create a whole new table and append it, the logic is the same:

```
// Create header row and append to table:
let table = this.rd.createElement("table");  
let tr1 = this.rd.createElement("tr");  
let tr1Th1 = this.rd.createElement("th");  
let tr1Text = this.rd.createText("Name")
this.rd.appendChild(table, tr1);
this.rd.appendChild(tr1, tr1Th1);
this.rd.appendChild(tr1Th1, tr1Text);

// add body row:
let tr2 = this.rd.createElement("tr");  
let tr2Td1 = this.rd.createElement("td");  
let tr2Text = this.rd.createText("John")
this.rd.appendChild(table, tr2);
this.rd.appendChild(tr2, tr2Td1);
this.rd.appendChild(tr2Td1, tr2Text);
```

Looks a bit ugly, but if you do it from your ComponentClass, I dont know other ways. And after that with @ViewChild grab your parent element and append that table to it. Add attributes with `setAttribute` method. To improve code you can use some loops or functional programming techniques.

---

Angular is not designed to work directly with DOM, so jQuery is a bad choice. In Angular, at these days, we use Renderer2.

Now in your issue, you first need to grab a reference of your `#time_table_table tbody` element. First thought might be to simply use the `ElementRef`:

```
constructor(el: ElementRef) {
  el.nativeElement.querySelector('#time_table_table tbody');
}
```

But you shouldn't use ElementRef to **modify the DOM**. For such task you can use `@ViewChild()`. It accepts a string parameter which is a name of your template variable. So `@ViewChild('myDiv') el:ElementRef` query would refer to `<div #myDiv> Foo </div>`.

Here is an example how you can do it:

```
import {ElementRef, Renderer2, ViewChild  } from '@angular/core';

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('yourVariable') el:ElementRef;

constructor(private rd: Renderer2){

ngOnInit() {   
  let btn = this.rd.createElement("button");  
  let text = this.rd.createText("Click")
  this.rd.appendChild(btn, text);
  this.rd.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement, btn)

  this.rd.listen(btn, "click", () => console.log(1));
}
```

You read about [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#createText) to learn more about its methods and properties.

Comment: using "createElement" & "createText" i can only create one tag, but i want to add one table using "appendChild" so how can i append?, can you please help me?

Comment: i want to append "<tr data-id="1"><td>Sunday<a (click)="assign(1)">Assign</a></td></tr>" this html in my table, with it's all attributes ans also (click)="assign(1)" CLICK Event. So is it Possible?

Comment: if i am use click Event then can i get it's value in Component in "assign(id)" function?

Comment: @Chaudhary - ok, i updated again. I havent tested this, though, but you get the idea - that would be a possible way to go

Comment: it works but how can i add attributes of all tag like i have " data-id='1' " in <tr> tag and " data-toggle='modal' " in <a> tag, so how can i add this?

Comment: @Chaudhary - Use `setAttribute()` - `this.rd.setAttribute(link1, 'data-id', '1');` ,  `link1` is your element you created before